# Tibco AMX Administrator: Empty page after login

Tags: firefox, console, admin, tibco

I have an issues with Tibco Active Matrix Administrator console and Firefox. After log-in I got an empty white page. Few days ago I hadn't this problem and it is looks like I have not changed anything in Firefox. 
Does anyone had this problem too and how it was fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I had faced this same issue a couple of months back. What i did to resolve was i noticed there was a plugin update on my FireFox browser which i felt hindered the Admin page to load. I just removed the updated plugin and also cleared my cookies. It worked soon after the restart of the browser and my machine. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is looks like the problem with Firefox. Firefox silently updated from v17 to v19 and this cause issues with admin page. So, to fix this issue user need to downgrade FF to v17